# Toggle results from database jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

I am very new to jQuery and JS. I have a set of links/buttons on my home page and I need to get the corresponding results from a database (which is functional) like the set of objects under a certain category. I need to have a toggle effect for the results. I am able to produce toggle effect for static data but I am unable to do the same with data retrieved from a database. Can someone please help me out .?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".trigger").click(function(){
  $(".panel").toggle("fast");
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  return false;
 });
});
</script>

Comment: The above is the code for toggle that we are using . But the problem we were facing was when I click on a button/link (which has the trigger class associated with it)  The function is being executed and the url is not being loaded. So I had to find some way to pass some the url on clicking a button to some other page and execute a function as well. I guess AJAX is the way to do it as posted here ..  even though we haven't figured out a way yet to do it yet..

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use Ajax to get the data from the server.

Have a look here.
http://www.php4every1.com/tutorials/jquery-ajax-tutorial/

and here http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/